# Monitor flickering, even with no signal

Tags: display

Today my [LG monitor](https://www.lg.com/uk/monitors/lg-29UM65-P) has started flickering. It does it even when the PC is turned off, and all I can see is the OSD menu.

I have been looking around on the OSD menu, and I have not managed to find any way to fix this issue.

Is my monitor broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely sounds like a hardware failure.  However, it is impossible to figure out what the issue is over the internet.

If the monitor is still under factory or store warranty, then this type of should be covered.  Even if the factory warranty is over, LG might offer paid servicing, or recommend a repair shop in your area.

Another possibility is that you might want to consider taking it to a TV repair shop.  If the issue is a blown capacitor, loose cable, bad power supply, etc, they should be able to diagnose and repair it.  However, you need to weigh the cost of the estimate/repair against the cost of paying for a full replacement.

Comment: funny thing happened... it solved by itself after turning it off for a while... -_-

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Thats good news.  However, if it happened once, it will probably happen again.  As I said, it definitely sounds like a hardware issue.  If it is under warranty, I would definitely have it looked it.

Comment: It is not under warranty. But I guess you are right, and there is a hardware issue. I will start looking for replacement befor it happens again. Thanks.

Comment: I already did it...